# How to test content of winston logger message in console

Tags: javascript, jestjs, winston

I am using Winston as my logger for my app, and I am trying to write unit tests (using Jest) for the logger message. I'm specifically trying to make sure no passwords are passed to my logs.

Since the logger outputs to `stdout`, I can't find a way to access what my `winston.error` function outputs and run my asserts on the log object.

I've tried several different ways to access the result of the logger and googled for solution without much success. This is my last iteration:

My logger.js (the content parameter is sanitized prior to passing it to the logger):

```
export const error = (content) => {
  return winston.error(content);
};
```

and my logger.spec.js:

```
const exampleLogs = { "email":"email", "password":"password" };

describe('Passwords are filtered out of Winston logger messages', () => {
  it('Should filter out password data from "error" level errors', () => {
    logger.error(exampleLogs);
    const result = jest.fn();
    expect(result).not.toHaveProperty('password');
  });
});
```

The test passes even though the password key is right there. When I `console.log(result)` I get a mock constructor object:

```
{ [Function: mockConstructor]
      _isMockFunction: true,
      getMockImplementation: [Function],
      mock: [Getter/Setter],
      mockClear: [Function],
      mockReset: [Function],
      mockRestore: [Function],
      mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
      mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function],
      mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function],
      mockReturnValue: [Function],
      mockResolvedValue: [Function],
      mockRejectedValue: [Function],
      mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
      mockImplementation: [Function],
      mockReturnThis: [Function],
      mockName: [Function],
      getMockName: [Function] }
```

But I was hoping to see my `exampleLogs` object... how can I access the object that the logger sends to `stdout`? any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mock your logger.error function, you must attribute the jest.fn() to it before you call it with the object. But I guess that is not what you want, right? You don't want to change the logger behavior, you just want to check its calls. If that's is the case, you wanna a Spy instead of a mock.

But there is another way to you check the logger output. Consider adding a file transport to your winston configuration (https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md). Then read the file and check if the expected output is there, then you delete the file.

Comment: Thanks Pedro! that's right- I am trying to get the actual result that the logger emits. Normally my logger pushes to a splunk-type service, but locally it just sends to stdout. I think your transports idea could work, gonna read up on it now and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pedro's solution is great. However, I used `stream` as transport to save the output in memory. Then, it is easier to read it and I do not need to delete any file.

You can find an example here: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/809#issuecomment-598966499